How to generate certain java classes from WSDL (not all of them)
I have to create lightweight java client. So I got 1 WSDL and few XSD Schema files from server, I`m using java17 and maven wsimport plugin this way:
      <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</wsdlDirectory>
                    <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                    <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources</bindingDirectory>
                    <bindingFiles>
                       <bindingFile>OCISchemaLogin.xsd</bindingFile>
                       <bindingFile>OCISchemaUser.xsd</bindingFile>
                       <bindingFile>OCISchemaGroup.xsd</bindingFile>            
                    </bindingFiles>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>myProjID</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>WebService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles> 
                            <packageName>my.package.name.soapClient</packageName>              
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

And it works well, I got my classes, builed successfully project and did some server calls, but service has a lot of stuff, and i got around ~800 java classes in my project, but Im using only 7 of them. How can I generate only few certain classes ?
Im trying to find  how to exclude other classes, but found only how to use certain source binding files with option  but its not what I need, maybe theres some extra VM options?
I also can remove them manualy, but this building have to be run on Jenkins side, and i need some better solution
